# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Query`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a problem with my data not showing up when I've posted data. I get the the following warning:

```
index.js:1437 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Query`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Query (at Queries.js:7)
    in GetEvents (at GetAllEvents1.js:8)
    in GetAllEvents1 (at Events.js:11)
    in div (at Events.js:9)
    in Events (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at AppRouter.js:24)
    in Switch (at AppRouter.js:21)
    in div (at AppRouter.js:14)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at AppRouter.js:13)
    in AppRouter (at App.js:34)
    in ApolloProvider (at App.js:33)
    in div (at App.js:32)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
```

My idea was to separate Queries and the GetAllEvents1 class. If i have these two in one class it works but when I don't, it doesn't.

This is the following code that I have.

The following is the GetAllEvents1 class:

```
import React from 'react';
import EventItem from './EventItem';
import {GetEvents} from './Queries';


function GetAllEvents1() {
    return(
    <GetEvents>
        {({loading, error, data})=> {
            if(loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>
            if(error) return <h1>Something went wrong, are you logged in?</h1>
            console.log(data.getAllEvents)
            return data.getAllEvents.map ((event) => (
                    <div key={event.id}>
                        <h1>Availaible events</h1>
                        <EventItem 
                        id={event.id} 
                        startDate={event.startDate} 
                        startTime={event.startTime} 
                        gps={event.gps} 
                        radius={event.radius} 
                        minAge={event.minAge} 
                        maxAge={event.maxAge}
                        gender={event.gender} 
                        runningPace={event.runningPace}
                        distance={event.distance}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))
            ;
        }}
    </GetEvents>
    )
    }
export default GetAllEvents1;
```

This is the other class, Queries:

```
import React from'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo';

export const GetEvents = () => {
    return (
    <Query query={gql`
        {
            getAllEvents {
                id
                startDate
                startTime
                gps
                radius
                minAge
                maxAge
                gender
                runningPace
                distance
            }
        }
    `}>
    </Query> 
    )
}
```

This next class is both of them as one. This class works. Notice that the only difference between these two codes is that I have surrounded the earlier two classes with return statements. If I don't I get the following error:

./src/components/events/GetAllEvents1.js
  Line 8:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
import React from 'react';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import EventItem from './EventItem';

const GetAllEvents = () => (
    <Query query={gql`
        {
            getAllEvents {
                id
                startDate
                startTime
                gps
                radius
                minAge
                maxAge
                gender
                runningPace
                distance
            }
        }
    `}>
        {({loading, error, data})=> {
            if(loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>
            if(error) return <h1>Something went wrong, are you logged in?</h1>
            console.log(data.getAllEvents)

            return data.getAllEvents.map ((event) => (
                    <div key={event.id}>
                        <h1>Availaible events</h1>
                        <EventItem 
                        id={event.id} 
                        startDate={event.startDate} 
                        startTime={event.startTime} 
                        gps={event.gps} 
                        radius={event.radius} 
                        minAge={event.minAge} 
                        maxAge={event.maxAge}
                        gender={event.gender} 
                        runningPace={event.runningPace} 
                        distance={event.distance}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))

            ;

        }}
    </Query>
);
export default GetAllEvents;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, you forgot to add `children` props for `GetEvents` in `Queries.js`:

```
import React from'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo';

export const GetEvents = ({children}) => {
    return (
    <Query query={gql`
        {
            getAllEvents {
                id
                startDate
                startTime
                gps
                radius
                minAge
                maxAge
                gender
                runningPace
                distance
            }
        }
    `}>
     {children} // here 
    </Query> 
    )
}
```